# Comparing dates

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, if-statement, nsdate

In my application I need to compare three dates in one if-else cycle. I have a start date, end date and the date of testing. What I want to check is whether the test date is between the start date and end date.

```
if (testDate >= startDate && testDate <= endDate) {
```

If I set the startDate to 25/04/2012 and the endDate to 24/04/2019 and the testDate to 25/12/2013 the code works. But if i set the startDate to 26/04/2000 and the endDate to 24/04/2019 and the testDate to 25/12/2013 the code does not works. What's wrong?

Comment: what did the search bring up?

Comment: Yes, you're comparing object addresses.  You must use a compare method supported by the object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dates can be compared like that. However, you must first call `timeIntervalSince1970` to convert the date to an integer type value. In this case, it gives you a numeric value of type `NSTimeInterval`.

The other option is to use the `compare:` method invoked on the `NSDate` object.

In that case, comparing one date to another will give a result detailed in the class reference as follows:

- The receiver and anotherDate are exactly equal to each other,
  NSOrderedSame
- The receiver is later in time than anotherDate, NSOrderedDescending
- The receiver is earlier in time than anotherDate, NSOrderedAscending.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot sanely compare Objective-C objects with any boolean operators in C. You'd be comparing their addresses, *not* their values.

Look at the documentation for the `NSDate` class, specifically the `-compare:` method.